# what is the way to share text from website to android apps as like send intent in android sdk

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, browser, share

Hello we are working on a mobile website. If user open this website in Google Chrome, there I have feature to share such as any article link something to android apps.

I am native android developer. I know how to share text from my native app to other apps using `Intent.ACTION_SEND`. We are looking to do same from mobile website. Is there any way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a good article on Intents with Chrome here :

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Another way in my opinion would be Enabling Deep Links for App Content:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents